# Undefined method 'url_for' while rendering a Rails 2.3.x template inside a ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncontroller, actionviewhelper

I know that this not an "acceptable" practice but as a background process I am caching a rendered Rails partial into the database for faster output via JSONP.  I have found many resources on the topic and successfully output a Rails 2.3.x partial within a ActiveRecord model, BUT if I use dynamic URLs within a partial Rails blows up.

I get a successful output (minus the dynamic URLs) with this...

```
def self.compile_html  

  viewer = Class.new(ApplicationController)
  path = ActionController::Base.view_paths rescue ActionController::Base.view_root

  Question.all.each do |q|
  q.html = ActionView::Base.new(path, {}, viewer).render(:partial => "questions/cached_output", :locals => { :question => q })  
  sleep 1 # hold for complete output and debugging only
  q.save( false ) # bypass validations
  end
  return "Caching complete"
end
```

I have tried including `ActionController::UrlWriter` Modules and `ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper` with no luck.  I cannot seems to find the instantiation/inclusion order to allow the partial to access `ActionController::Base.new.url_for()` to write the dynamic routes to the partial.

I did attempt a similar process as [RoR: undefined method `url_for' for nil:NilClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538821/ror-undefined-method-url-for-for-nilnilclass) without luck

I know that render_anywhere is a solution for Rails 3.x apps, but I am working in Rails 2.3.11

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I have an old app that I had to do something similar (but made use of `polymorphic_path` and `polymorphic_url`) in a model.

The following includes gave me access to `url_for` and `polymorphic_path` etc.

```
include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
include ActionController::PolymorphicRoutes
include ActionController::UrlWriter
```

Comment: Was the included by ActionView::Base or ActionController::Base?

Comment: I used those files in a model of mine, it wasn't inside a view or controller- it was inside something that extended ActiveRecord::Base